# How to access spice sharp library in unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, sharp

I get to know about this project
Spice sharp-
https://github.com/SpiceSharp/SpiceSharp

My question is how can acess this library using unity.

Answer (score 0):

You try the following steps:

1. In the URL option, paste the URL of the repository, select the local location of the repository.

   [image]

   [image]

   directory of the repository: C:\temp\SpiceSharp-master
2. Open Unity3d, create a new project, note that the location of the unity project should be placed in the directory of the repository.

Comment: I placed spice library, but how can I access it to run my code ?

Comment: Can anyone one show one code example of using it inside unity?